# Deserialize multidimensional JSON API Response with JSMSerializerBundle

Tags: json, symfony, json-deserialization, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I work with Symfony2/JSMSerializerBundle.

Serializing flat json objects to PHP objects works great. But the API I use, gives a multidimensional Json response:

```
{
"Webmessage": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "Header": {
        "Country": "NL",
        "Language": "NL"
    },
    "Content": {
        "Filters": {
            "Sizes": {
                "Size": [
                    {
                        "@id": "241",
                        "#text": "3,5"
                    },
                    {
                        "@id": "55",
                        "#text": "36"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Colours": {
                "Colour": [
                    {
                        "@id": "159",
                        "#text": "wit"
                    },
                    {
                        "@id": "54",
                        "#text": "zwart"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

As deserialized PHP I want something like this:

```
Array
(
[sizes] => Array
    (
      [0] => AppBundle\Entity\Filter Object
      (
        [id:AppBundle\Entity\Filter:private] => 1
        [text:AppBundle\Entity\Filter:private] => Heren
       )

      [1] => AppBundle\Entity\Filter Object
      (
        [id:AppBundle\Entity\Filter:private] => 2
        [text:AppBundle\Entity\Filter:private] => Dames
      )
    )

[colour] => Array
    (
      [0] => AppBundle\Entity\Filter Object
      (
        [id:AppBundle\Entity\Filter:private] =>56
        [text:AppBundle\Entity\Filter:private] => Black
       )

      [1] => AppBundle\Entity\Filter Object
      (
        [id:AppBundle\Entity\Filter:private] => 212
        [text:AppBundle\Entity\Filter:private] => Yellow
      )
    )
```

)

Who has tips how i can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with the `deserialize()` JMS' method?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can decode it first and then use the Normalizer to create the entities. Something like this:

```
$array= json_decode($json, true);
$valueToDenormalize = $array['value'];

$normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();
$entity = $normalizer->denormalize($valueToDenormalize, 'Your\Class');
```

Be aware, I have not tried this. I don't know if the normalizer will work this way, but I know it's used to normalize and denormalize between arrays and Symfony's entities.

For further investigation you could take a look at the Serializer docs:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Or the Normalizer:
http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/GetSetMethodNormalizer.html

Here's something about json_encode:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php